# Finding the top pixel location of the virtual keyboard?

Tags: android

Is there a way to find the top position of the virtual keyboard? I'd like to place a view directly above it when it's open. Something like:

```
 -----------------------------
 | my linear layout | button |
 -----------------------------  <-- what's this y position?
 |                           |
 |    virtual keyboard       |
 |                           |
```

I figured I could reposition my view when the keyboard is open so long as I know where the top edge of the keyboard is. Or maybe instead, there's some kind of layout I can use which puts a view in the same z level as the keyboard, and just pins it to the top of the keyboard automatically? That'd be rad.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that you have is set your view to align:parentBottom="true"

then in your manifest put`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` on the activity that you are in. This will make it so that your views that are aligned bottom will jump up on top of the soft keyboard while it is open.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I added the `windowSoftInputMode` under `<activity>` and I added the alignBottom to my view, but it stays on the bottom of the view. Any help?